# Surjective linear transformation perserves dimension?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $\phi$ be a **surjective** linear transformation on linear space $V$ (not necessarily of finite dimension), $U$ is a $r$-dimension subspace of $V$.

Prove that: $\phi(U)$ is a $r$-dimension subspace of $V$.

---

It is quite obvious when $\dim(V)$ is finite. I am confused when it goes to $\dim(V) = \infty$

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot prove it, since it is false. Suppose that $V$ is the vector space of all sequences of real numbers and that$$\phi(a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots)=(a_2,a_3,a_4,\ldots).$$Then $\phi$ is surjective. And if $U=\{(x,0,0,0,\ldots)\mid x\in\Bbb R\}$, then $U$ is $1$-dimensional and $\phi(U)$ is $0$-dimensional.

Comment: I see. A very succinct sample!